# Parameters set to null on call to function

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a table with some fields. The problem is that the player and serieType are set to null when pressing the save button. The selectoneMenu items are correctly set when using them. It's only when you press the button they are set to null.

```
    <p:dataTable id="scores" var="aScore" value="#{serviceScoreDB.scoresList }" 
     border="1">

        <p:column id="playerName">
            <f:facet name="header">Namn</f:facet>
            <p:commandLink value="#{aScore.playerName}">

            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="player">
            <f:facet name="header">Spelare</f:facet>
             Spelare
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{player}"
                converter="playerConverter" id="playerList">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{servicePlayer.allPlayers}"
             var="n"
             itemValue="#{n}"
             itemLabel="#{n.combinedName}"
             itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
              <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{serviceHCP.getClubs(player) }" update="test" 
              render="test" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>                  

        </p:column>

        <p:column id="club">
            <f:facet name="header">Klubb</f:facet>
            <h:outputText  id="test" value="#{serviceHCP.myCurrentClub.name}"></h:outputText>       
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="serieType">
            <f:facet name="header">Spelare</f:facet>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{serviceSerieType.mySerieType}" 
                converter="serieTypeConverter" id="serieTypeList">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{serviceSerieType.serieTypes}"
                 var="st"
                 itemValue="#{st}"
                 itemLabel="#{st.serie_type}"
                 itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
                 <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" update="sType"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="ssType">
            <f:facet name="header">SerieType</f:facet>
            <h:outputText  id="sType" value="#{serviceSerieType.mySerieType}"></h:outputText>       
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="playDate">
            <f:facet name="header">Datum</f:facet>
            <div class="text-input">
                <h:inputText id="pDate" value="#{aScore.playDate}"  style="width: 100px; border: none; background: none;" readonly="true">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
                </h:inputText>
            </div>
            <!-- h:outputText value="#{aScore.playDate}" >
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
            </h:outputText  -->
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="serieNo">
            <f:facet name="header">Antal Serier</f:facet>
            <h:inputText id="serieNumber" value="#{aScore.serieNo}"  style="width: 75px; border: none; background: none;" readonly="true">

            </h:inputText>
            <!-- h:outputText value="#{aScore.serieNo}" /  -->
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="laneNo">
            <f:facet name="header">Bana</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{aScore.laneNo}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="hcp">
            <f:facet name="header">Hcp</f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="testing" value="#{aScore.hcp}" />
        </p:column>         

        <p:column id="totalScore">
            <f:facet name="header">Total poäng</f:facet>
            <div class="text-input">
                <h:inputText id="scoreID" value="#{aScore.totalScore}"  style="width: 75px; border: none; background: none;" readonly="true"></h:inputText>
            </div>
            <!-- h:outputText value="#{aScore.totalScore}" / -->
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="save">
            <f:facet name="header">Spara</f:facet>
            <p:commandButton value="Visa lista" action="#{serviceScoreDB.saveScores(player, serviceHCP.myCurrentClub, 
            serviceSerieType.mySerieType, aScore.playDate, aScore.totalScore, aScore.serieNo)}">


            </p:commandButton>      
        </p:column>         




    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: What's the scope of `ServiceSerieType` and `ServicePlayer` ? You should use `actionListener` attribute instead of `action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commandButton is executing and submitting values for ALL values in the form.

If any form field in the form submission has failed its validation then none of the values will be submitted.  This could be why `player` and `serieType` are being passed as null in your arguments to the action method.  The Action method will run in the Invoke Application phase after all validations and form submissions have occurred.

My suggestion is to try specifying a `p:ajax` tag for the commandButton so that only the fields you want are processed and rendered.  This might fix your problem but this is all I can tell from the code that you have posted.

Comment: Correct an ajax solution fixed the problem but lead to another problem. It will execute while populating the table. I can't seem to find an event for the button.

Comment: Hmmm not sure I understand.  Maybe you should post another question since it is a different problem?